# How do I make my character stop going left in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I have this code and my character can go left, right and jump. I don't want the character going left, so how can I remove that. (I'm very new with coding)

```
public class Player: MonoBehaviour {

    public float maxspeed = 10f;
    bool facingRight = true;

    Animator anim;

    bool grounded = false;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    float groundRadius = 0.2f;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    public float jumpFocre = 500f;

    bool doubleJump = false;

    void Start ()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
        anim.SetBool ("Ground", grounded);

        if (grounded)
            doubleJump = false;

        float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (move));

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(move * maxspeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if((grounded || !doubleJump) && Input.GetKeyDown ("up"))
        {
            anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpFocre));

            if(!doubleJump && !grounded)
            doubleJump = true;
        }
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;    
    }
}
```

Comment: ...just left? The character can still turn right though?

Comment: I just want the charater to go right and jump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
   ...
   if (grounded) doubleJump = false;
   static float move; //Only allocate memory once
   move = Mathf.Max(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0); //New; nullify negative values
   //move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");  //Old; positive and negative
   anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (move));
   ...
}
```

or

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
   ...
   static float move; //Only allocate memory once
   move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
   if (move > 0) //Only respond to positive values
   {
      anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (move));
      GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(...);
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the `static` keyword is valid here, since we're inside a method, not defining a class member. Local numeric variables like this end up on the stack or in registers anyway, so memory allocation isn't a concern here.